# Adding a line break in an adobe PDF field with coldfusion

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, line-breaks

I'm using the following to create a multiline text box in an adobe pdf using `<cfpdfform    action = "populate"`, and I'm having difficulty understanding the behavior.

```
<cfset NewLine = "&##10;" />
<cfset Field1Value = "Name #NewLine#" />
<cfset Field1Value &= "Address #NewLine#" />

<cfset Field2Value = "Some Info #NewLine#" />
<cfset Field2Value &= "Line Two #NewLine#" />
```

The first field populates as

`Name
Address`

The second populates as

`Some Info`

I've confirmed that the actual value is `Some Info &#xD; Line Two`

Thinking it was a problem with the field, I deleted field two, and copied field 1 over and changed the name, but it still populates the same way. I'm not sure how to diagnose this.

Multi-line is checked, and it accepts manual entry of line breaks if I open the pdf with adobe acrobat.

If it's relevant, the first field is on page 1 and the second on page 2. I'm not sure what other details might be important to add.

Comment: Check the field type and settings.  I vaguely recall something about having to enable multi-line in the field properties when you create the form in Acrobat, etc..

Comment: I did check this. Multi-line is checked. And if I manually fill the form it will accept line breaks (via the enter key).

Comment: Sorry, without seeing the form, that's all I can think of.

Comment: I solved this using NewLine = "#chr(10)##chr(13)#" instead. Do you know why this worked?

Comment: (Update) Oh.. think I misunderstood the question. Sounded like it worked with one field, but not the other. No idea why that would be unless they're using different `NewLine` chars or the field settings are different. AFAIK, the line break character is `chr(10)`.

Comment: "the line break character is chr(10)" Though I might be wrong and thinking of Excel...